# C# вывод изображения.

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая проблема. Вывести изображение получается только если оно имеется в папке с exe файлом. А мне необходимо написать программу, которая бы отрисовывала изображение на форме без его наличия, то есть был 1 exe файл без каких либо других файлов. Как это сделать? Где можно найти подробную информацию?

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните изображение в ресурсах и загружайте оттуда.

Comment: @Чад а после этого как обратиться к примеру PicB.image = ...?

Comment: Что-то типа  `PicB.image = Resources.myImage;`

Вообще погуглите по словам Resources image c# :-)